# Network Wide Security / Access Control Software

Tags: networking, security

Is there a way to have a network wide, intrusion / attack detection system running on a Raspberry Pi? Kinda like fail2ban but for everything as well as access control to restrict certain devices from accessing the internet? I currently have a Pi hooked up running pi-hole, so I'd like another, network related use for it. It would be even better if it could stop malware and virus etc.

Please don't suggest OpenWRT as my router doesn't support it.

Comment: You've asked this question before...

Comment: Yes because it got no where so I reposted it and now because you down voted its going no where again. Thanks mate! @Jacobm001

Comment: As I'm sure was mentioned on the previous attempt (that has been deleted), this question is off topic. It's not specific to the RPi in any way. It's a general networking question, not an RPi question.

Comment: Well then where would you like me to post it then? Cause it will probably get moved into off topic there as well since its on a RPi.

Comment: Deleting a question and reposting is not the way to get an answer, it will only serve to annoy those who can help.

Comment: You could try our larger sibling [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) -- although they may or may not treat this question any more seriously, at least this puts you on a better track since the kind of security you are talking about starts with *the operating system, not the brand of hardware*.  Would you go to an Acme motherboard forum and say, "I have a computer with an Acme mobo running Windows 7, what should I do to prevent malware?"  Also, you need to focus in a bit beyond simply a paranoia of everything.  If you are afraid of everything, unplug the pi and it will be safe.

Comment: There's also [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/), but beware they have a professional focus and are even meaner than we are ;)

Comment: Finally, you'll probably be thrilled to learn of the existence of [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) which I believe should run on Raspbian.  "Thrilled" that is, until you actually start using it, at which point the learning curve of hardening a system may start to look steep.   If you had bothered to do any research at all rather than just asking the same question over and over, BTW, you'd already know about this...but good luck.

Comment: Thanks, yes I learnt the hard way that Stack exchange can be really mean :(

Comment: Hey, I thought that too about programming forums (albeit before SE existed).  Eventually you may realize *why* it has to be that way.   Short version:  There are way more people who ask questions than answer them/are capable of answering them, and so we have to apply filters.  Unfortunately that means being a bit blunt sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But it's difficult because there are so many sub forms. Like from now on I'll have to scroll through them all to find the most suitable one.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to route all your traffic through the machine in question (which is not something you have to do for pihole), and whether the Pi has enough CPU to do this depends on your network speed/utilization, but what you want to look at is Kismet Wireless (www.kismetwireless.net).